# Sum from the joined table in sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to sum the amount from the tbl_paid where transaction_num has same number and tbl_client.c_id = tbl_paid.c_id.

Basically means I am trying to add the amount of 3359 and 1 where there c_id = 172 and transaction_num = 2 because they have the same record. Row 1 and 2 and then the other is as is.

[image]

tbl_client

[image]

tbl_paid

[image]

Look at the first picture to see the query I used to join table and get the output.

What I am trying to do with my query is to show all the records from tbl_client joined by tbl_paid who are accounts that are paid today. If the pay twice this day the record of the amount will be added to the existing payment.

Comment: Please don't show images. Instead copy the data as text into your request. Then, please show sample data and the expected result. And then, you are not using MySQL *and* SQL Server *and* MariaDB. Please tag your request only with the one DBMS you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show clients with their today's total payment. So, select the total payment per client and then join this to the client table.

```
select c.*, p.total
from tbl_client c
join 
(
  select c_id, sum(amount) as total
  from tbl_paid
  where pay_date = current_date()
  group by c_id
) p on p.c_id = c.c_id
order by c.c_id;
```

If you want to show clients with no current payment, too, then change the inner join to an outer join.

**UPDATE:** In the comments to ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ's answer you say you want to see the different transactions. If this is so, then you don't want the total per client, but the total per client and transaction, which is a very small change in the query:

```
select c.*, p.transaction_num, p.total
from tbl_client c
join 
(
  select c_id, transaction_num, sum(amount) as total
  from tbl_paid
  where pay_date = current_date()
  group by c_id, transaction_num
) p on p.c_id = c.c_id
order by c.c_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

`sum()` and `group by` is what you need.

```
select t3.*, t4.*
from tbl_client t4    
inner join
    (select sum(t2.amount) as amt, t1.transaction_num, t1.c_id
        from tbl_client t1
        inner join tbl_paid t2 on t1.c_id = t2.c_id
        where t1.pay_date = current_date()
        group by t1.transaction_num, t1.cid
    ) t3 on t3.c_id = t4.c_id
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but does not get what i want.

Comment: the first 2 lines should merge and sum the amount on the output and become 1 line.

Comment: so only first 2 lines of 172 and 173? or only 172?

Comment: nope. they should merge because the have same c_id and transaction_num value.

Comment: and the other that has no pair will be as is.

Comment: @ArvinJasonCabrera,  try my new query

Comment: I post a picture of the column of the table

Comment: great. seems what's need to be updated is the amount column, try the updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203300/discussion-between--and-arvin-jason-cabrera).

Comment: This doesn't look correct. It's not a client that has a transaction number, but the payment. By the way: The query would be easier to read, did you use better alias names. Generic names like t1, t2, etc. tend to obfuscate queries. Use mnemonic names like c for client and p for payment instead.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I'm comfortable using t1, t2... etc, specially when there's a need for subqueries and self join.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUM() :

```
 select SUM(amount), t1.transaction_num
   from tbl_client t1
   left join tbl_paid t2 on t1.c_id = t2.c_id
   where t1.transaction_num = 2 and t1.c_id = 172`
```